# Oracle column Datatype from metadata

Tags: oracle

I want to distinguish between Number type and decimal Type columns in oracle, in the oracle metadata all_tab_columns, all_tab_cols they are showing datatype of a column as Number only (there is no column in metadata which is capturing flag or decimal precision, etc) is there a way to find if a column has Datatype like Number(10,3),

I did some research in google, most of the solutions were to write a dynamic query on the table and process the data and make a decision if its a decimal or whole number, Problem in my case is I don't have any data in the table, yet my requirement is to know if the column data type is Number or Number(x,y).

Please advice

Thanks
Bharat

Comment: The information you are looking for is in the columns `DATA_PRECISION` and `DATA_SCALE`

Comment: *"there is no column in metadata which is capturing ... decimal precision "* Really? What about [DATA_SCALE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2102.htm#REFRN20276)?

Comment: I saw that column Data_scale, But unfortunately its always null for both Number and Number(x,y)

Comment: my database version is 12, USER_TAB_COLUMNS table has hardly 10 rows - not what I was looking for.